# What does the word “property” mean in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

The book *Software Abstractions* frequently uses the term “property.” It is arguably one of the most important words in the book. Here are a few examples of its use:

Simulation involves finding instances of states or executions that satisfy a given **property**. Checking involves finding a counterexample-an instance that violates a given **property**.

There's no explicit mutation here; instead, the before and after states of the book are given different names (b and b'), and the effect of the operation is captured by a **property** relating them.

Predicate calculus lacks transitive closure, so reachability **properties** can't be expressed.

An atom is a primitive entity that is

• indivisible: it can't be broken down into smaller parts;

• immutable: its **properties** don't change over time; and

• uninterpreted: it doesn't have any built-in **properties**, the way numbers do, for example.

What is a "property"? What does the word “property” mean in Alloy?